# When sorting of itab is done in SQL query?

Tags: sorting, abap, hana, internal-tables

I have a select like this

```
DATA lt_data TYPE SORTED TABLE OF T_TYPE1 WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY col1.
SELECT col1, col2 INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_data where...
```

My question is: will the sorting operation be performed on the DB or on the application server side? My DB is Hana DB (S/4 Hana).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapinto_clause.htm) states that a sorting process is executed **after** the result set is inserted into the table thus it takes place on the application server.

> *The results set is inserted into the internal table itab row-by-row; a sorting process is executed in the case of a sorted table.*